# Fetch only those contacts which are saved in my database

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm creating a Cordova Phonegap Application. Using following code, I can fetch all contacts which are saved in my PhoneBook. But I want to fetch only those contacts which are saved in my database. Here, I'm using jQuery Mobile also.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
        <title>Contact Example</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"/>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            function onDeviceReady() 
            { 
                var options = new ContactFindOptions(); // specify contact search criteria

                options.filter="";          // empty search string returns all contacts

                options.multiple=true;      // return multiple results

                filter = ["displayName", "phoneNumbers"];

                navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options); // find contacts

            }

            //onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts

            function onSuccess(contacts) 
            {
                $("#userList").html('');

                for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)
                {
                   var htmlData="<li><a href='#' data-role='button' id='btn"+i+"' data-id='"+i+"' data-con='"+contacts[i].displayName+"' data-flag='"+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value+"' onclick='giveme_result(this);'>" +contacts[i].displayName+ "<p class='ui-li-aside'>" + contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value+ "</p></a></li><br/>";

                   $("#userList").append(htmlData).listview('refresh');
                }  
             };

             function giveme_result(ref)
             { 
                    var i = $(ref).attr("data-id");

                    var con_name = $(ref).attr("data-con");

                    var flag = $(ref).attr("data-flag");

                    if( flag != null)
                    {
                        $.mobile.changePage ($("#page2"), { transition : "none", reverse : false });

                        document.getElementById("num_content").innerHTML = "Mobile Number : " + flag + "<br/>";

                        document.getElementById("con_name").innerHTML = "Name : " + con_name + "<br/>";

                        $("#profile_btn").live("click" , function(){

                            $.mobile.changePage($("#page3"), {transition : "none", reverse : true })
                        })
                    }
              }

            function onError(contactError)
            { 
                alert('onError!');
            }

      </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role = "page" id = "index">

         <div data-role="content"> 
              <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search..." id="userList">  </ul>
         </div>

     </div> 
     <!------------ index_end------------------->

     <div data-role = "page" id = "page2">

         <div data-role="content" id = "num_content"></div>

         <div data-role="content" id = "con_name"></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**PS :**  Created web service in PHP for database interaction. I have also added contact and file transfer plugins.
Can anybody help as soon as possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nobody's there to answer my question?? I think all talented programmers r enjoying weekend.. :-/

Comment: Read the entire phonebook. Read your entire contact list in your database. Cross reference them and then show the ones that exists in both lists.

Comment: Can u please elaborate? Any example?

Comment: Earlier also I followed ur tutorials. You explained everything very nicely. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks :). I have no examples though. Read both the phonebook ans your own contacts in an array and compare each record with every record in the other arrays. Then fish out the doubles and show them.